# Disable a method in a class that is NOT mocked

Tags: php, phpunit, php-7

I have a simple class with a parser

```
class Parser
{
    public function __construct(P1 $p1, P2 $p2)
    {
        $this->p1 = $p1;
        // etc...
    }

    public function parse()
    {
        $this->doSomething1();
        return $this->doSomething2(P3 $p3);
    }
}
```

then I have my test class

```
class ParserTest
{
    public function testParse()
    {

      $p1 = $this->getMockBuilder(P1::class)->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();
      $p2 = $this->getMockBuilder(P2::class)->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();
      $p3 = $this->getMockBuilder(P3::class)->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();
     
      $parser = new Parser ($p1, $p2);
      $result = $parser->parse($p3);

    }
}
```

what I need to do is disable doSomething1 for the test because it is basically doing an API call, so I can test what is in result. How can I do that?

Comment: This is a sign you need to refactor your code. A parser should not be fetching data through an API, it should only parse given data. It would be wise to extract the fetching to a separate service class and pass its result to the `parse` method as an argument.

Comment: yeah I suspected I had to do that, I was just wandering there was a faster way. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Which visibility have the `doSomething1` method? Probably you could use a partial mock...

Answer (score 1):

As El_Vanja already suggested, it's best to extract that API call. If you can't do it right now, you can override the `doSomething1` method for the test:

```
class ParserTest
{
    public function testParse()
    {
      $p1 = $this->getMockBuilder(P1::class)->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();
      $p2 = $this->getMockBuilder(P2::class)->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();
      $p3 = $this->getMockBuilder(P3::class)->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();
     
      $parser = new class($p1, $p2) extends Parser {
            protected function doSomething1()
            {
            }
      };

      $result = $parser->parse($p3);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a PHPUnit partial mock (I didn't find a valid doc for this, only some PR or in the source code) of your class under test, as example:

```
    $methods = ["doSomething1"];


    $parser = $this->getMockBuilder(Parser::class)
        ->disableOriginalClone()
        ->disableArgumentCloning()
        ->disallowMockingUnknownTypes()
        ->onlyMethods($methods)
        ->setConstructorArgs([$p1, $p2])
        ->getMock();
```

NB: Because you need to pass data in the constructor you can't use the short-cat version:

```
    $this->createPartialMock(Parser::class, $methods);
```